# React Native ios firestore malfunctions on some networks

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I don't understand why this exactly happens but firestore fails to work on certain wifi networks. This issue specifically occurs on ios devices when I deploy my app on the device. On certain networks, the app doesn't get any documents while on some networks documents fail to write. But then when I change my network to mobile data the app starts working again. And the network quality isn't the issue as everything else works perfectly fine on the same network. Has anybody else come across such an issue? Firestore behaving unpredictably on certain networks? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if your `wifi` network is ok , maybe `firebase` blocked your internet provider. some countries blocked with google `firebase` , you can change your `ip` with some `proxy` application and try that.